# Keycloak Admin CLI - Updating a realm with JSON file

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-admin-cli

**Objective:**
Our objective is to update the entire realm provided a json file.

**Problem:**
The issue at hand is we cannot seem to update the realm entirely to include the client changes as well.

**Actions taken:**
Option 1:
Based on the [Keycloak Admin CLI documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#the-admin-cli), a Keycloak realm can be updated from a JSON file using the following command:

`kcadm.sh update realms/demorealm -f demorealm.json`

However, when making an update to a property within the `clients` section of the JSON file (i.e. a client's description), the change is not reflected within the Keycloak realm.

We also tried to take a look at the `kcadm.sh help update` . We tried to utilize the merge flag (Merge new values with existing configuration on the server. Merge is automatically enabled unless `--file` is specified) . We do have a file specified and therefore tried to enable it using the flag - but to no success. The clients did not change as expected.

Option 2:
We have tried the partial import command found in [Keycloak documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/admin-cli.adoc)

`$ kcadm.sh create partialImport -r demorealm -s ifResourceExists=OVERWRITE-o -f demorealm.json`

With the `ifResourceExists` set to `OVERWRITE`, it accurately changes clients. However, it alters other Realm configurations such as assigned users roles. Ex: After manually creating a new user via the Keycloak UI and setting roles for the user, the roles are lost after running the command with the `OVERWRITE` flag set. Setting the `ifResourceExists` to `SKIP` does not properly update values for a client as it is skipped altogether.

**Question:**
Is it possible, either with a different command or different flags, to update a Keycloak realm in its entirety with a single Keycloak admin command? Neither Option 1 or Option 2 listed above worked for us. We want to avoid making individual `update client` calls when updating the Realm.

**Notes:**
We have properly authenticated and confirmed that changes made at the realm level are reflected in Keycloak.

Comment: Also, note that using OVERWRITE removes all user roles in the ovewrite even if your file contains the same ID's.

Answer (score 9):

After further research, the approach we decided to go with is to update realm level settings with:

`kcadm.sh update realms/demorealm -f demorealm.json`

We then iterate over the clients and add/update them with:

`kcadm.sh update clients/{clients-uuid} -f clientfile.json`

Since the previous command does not update client roles, we must then use the following command to add the roles:

`kcadm.sh update clients/{clients-uuid}/roles/{role-name} -f rolefile.json`

Finally, to add in composite roles, we use this command:

`kcadm.sh add-roles --cclientid {clientID} --rid {id of client role} --rolename {name of role to add}`